# Can a normal bicycle be adapted as a draisine (to use on abandoned railways with the tracks in place)?

Tags: conversion, draisine

For a long time I've wanted to rent a draisine and ride it down an old abandoned railway.  There's dozens of places in Scandinavia where one can do so.

[image: Draisine in Sweden]
*Source: Jonas Andréasson, [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kilometertavla_2.jpg)*

[image: Draisine in Norway]
*Source: [Dresinsykling på Flekkefjordbanen](http://www.flekkefjordbanen.no/index.php/nyere-bilder)*

Alternately, is it feasible to adapt an ordinary bicycle as a draisine?  Preferably in an easy way so I can ride to an abandoned railway, attach some stuff, and continue onto the railway.

Do any kits to easily convert a regular bicycle into a draisine exist?

Comment: I presume you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draisine) rather than [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandy_horse) as the latter would just mean removing the pedals.  Googling "rail bike" seems to give some DIY options.  I read a mention just this morning, maybe here.

Comment: @ChrisH I do, as should be clear from context on using it on an abandoned railway.  The mention you read might have been [on Outdoors.SE](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/15074/566).

Comment: It was (almost) clear from the first paragraph, explicitly so from the second.  But the title could go either way. As ex railways often have the rails removed they would be nice flat trails for trying out unusual/vintage bike designs, so the other meaning wouldn't be completely absurd.  You're right about the outdoors.se question

Comment: I believe that I can answer your question, just give me some time to find some sources.

Comment: "For a long time I've wanted to rent a draisine and ride it down an old abandoned railway. There's dozens of places in Scandinavia where one can do so." Does that mean that there are places where one may *rent* a draisine and ride it or *only* ride one, if one were to posses one in the first place? (I should find the prospect of doing so immensely appealing.)

Comment: Just a thought:  It would seem that starting with a fat tire bike might be the simplest.  One could simply remove the tires (perhaps wrapping the rims with rubber) rather than needing to have a complex setup to keep the wheels centered on the rail.  The outrigger would still be needed, though, to maintain overall balance.

Comment: [...or you could just brush up your skills a bit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gywAgQ0z64I&t=1m6s) ;-)

Comment: @gschenk Rent+ride for sure.  Whether those companies who rent them out have an exclusive right to the tracks, I don't know; I expect it's rather rare for people to own a draisine or a kit to construct one.

Comment: Which side do you pass on?

Comment: @CraigHicks You'd have to take the entire draisine off the tracks if you want to pass or meet.  Not for busy commuting areas :-)

Comment: What about a 4 inch wheel from a far tire rim. Could that allow enough room to balance?

Comment: I'm going to see if I can 3D print two rims for connection to the bike. Will post what I make.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes a regular bicycle can be adapted as a draisine or a railbike as we call them (to use on abandoned railways with the tracks in place)?

California, USA is big into this sort of thing. There are more books on the subject than websites to be sure of.

Although there are so many styles of railbikes out there, it would be quite difficult to know what would fit your needs, but I am fairly confident this site will be able to help you: [Bentley Railbike CONSTRUCTION PLANS](http://rrbike.freeservers.com/).

I take it, that you are looking into something like this:

[image: Bentley Railbike]

They offer **Bentley Railbike CONSTRUCTION PLANS** for sale and they look like they are detachable, but you should confirm this with this company via email, writing or by phone to verify your needs.

> CONSTRUCTION PLANS include 6 pages of text with detailed construction sequence and parts list keyed to the drawings, plus 10 sheets of drawings with most parts rendered full scale.
>
> - Easy construction - no welding or complex machining.
> - Adjustable outrigger wheel height.
> - **Detach outrigger with 3 pins - folds after removal.**
> - Wheel guide lift lever.
>
> This is a proprietary design, and a patent shall be applied for in the near future.
>
> A LICENSE (plans included) to construct a railbike in accordance with these plans may be purchased for $25 (US DOLLARS).

A Railbike - **LIST of Parts and Materials** can be seen [here.](http://rrbike.freeservers.com/Railbike_Construction_Notes.htm)

Comment: That front wheel steering mechanism looks absolutely terrifying.  Its a big stabby spear aimed at the rider's chest.

Comment: I think it's actually used to pull the steerer off the rail, and if so you could probably replace it with a rope.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has commented on the possibility of taking a normal bike with wheel rims without tires. This would need wide rims to fit around the top of the rail. This would involve a certain amount of wear of the rim though.

Comment: Welcome to the site! The fact that a wide rim profile allows one to put a bike onto a rail solves only one problem. It leaves other problems unanswered however: how to attach the third wheel sliding on another rail, where suspension comes from (as air in tires is gone), how efficient braking will be with metal-on-metal contact (rubber is gone) etc.

Comment: Such a bike would be completely unrideable, since you'd be unable to steer for balance.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Interesting thought - you could balance using body weight, but it would be an active input needing continuous work to maintain.  Plus the consequences of falling on railway ties would mean more damage than an off-road fall.  OP's original question definitely wants an outrigger wheel for balance and ease of riding on rails.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov rails are quite smooth - a railway carriage or engine gets away with leaf springs.  Modern rails are fusion welded to minimise the clack-clack between sections.  So its possible the only suspension needed might be served by a padded saddle.   Trains also run wheels without rubber, and while their braking is abysmal compared to any other transport (including aeroplanes!) its still sufficient given the rails are empty of all other traffic.

Comment: Rims are generally made of aluminum. That's not exactly the kind of material you want to roll your entire weight on. Especially when the aluminum is rather thin. The wear is like that of hammering on your rims three to four times per second with quite a heavy hammer. How many minutes do you think the rims will last?

Comment: @Criggie I'm afraid keeping the bike stable with body weight would not work. Bicycles are online stable when turning. To ride along a line you alternate left and right turns. Unless the rims were quite a bit wider than a rail the bike would be forced into a straight line. In consequence, it would be unstable. A skilled rider can ride with tyres on a railroad rail. The same with a tyre-less bike with wide enough rims for stability would be a more skillful trick.

Comment: @gschenk I wish I had the ability to test this - as a thought experiment its inconclusive.   You're right its not a stable system, which is why I called it "active input"   I have a railway handy, but its most definitely in use.

Comment: It is disheartening how little thought is given to interesting physics problems when one is concerned about sharing the same section of rail with a train.